# Arquillian Cube REST-Assured integration test

Tags: java, docker, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to test my REST API with a remote tomcat server in docker. Following is the details of it:

**Update Sep 21, 2017: -START-**

Found that there is some issue with Arquillian Cube-RESTEasy testing since arquillian cube has dependency on docker-java which uses Jersey as JAXRS provider. [See for more details](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-cube/issues/57)

Do we have any workaround for the above mentioned issue?

**Update Sep 21, 2017: -END-**

**arquillian.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<extension qualifier="docker"> 
  <property name="serverVersion">1.28</property> 
  <property name="serverUri">http://localhost:2375</property> 
  <property name="definitionFormat">CUBE</property>
  <property name="dockerContainers"> 
      tomcat:
        image: tutum/tomcat:7.0
        exposedPorts: [8089/tcp]
        await:
          strategy: polling
          stdErr: true
        env: [TOMCAT_PASS=mypass, JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8089 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false]
        portBindings: [8080/tcp]
  </property>
</extension>

<container qualifier="tomcat" default="true"> 
  <configuration>
      <property name="host">localhost</property> 
      <property name="httpPort">8080</property> 
      <property name="user">admin</property> 
      <property name="pass">mypass</property>
  </configuration>
</container>

<extension qualifier="cube">
    <property name="connectionMode">STARTORCONNECTANDLEAVE</property>
</extension>

</arquillian>
```

**Testcase:**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class GoalTypeServicesTest {

    @Deployment(testable=false)
    public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, GoalTypeServicesTest.class.getName()+".war")
                .addClass(CommissionServicesApplication.class)
                .addClass(GoalTypeServicesTest.class)
                .addClass(ArquillianAbstractRestApiTest.class)
                .addClass(GoalTypeServices.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource("web.xml");
    }

    @ArquillianResource
    RequestSpecBuilder requestSpecBuilder;

    @ArquillianResource
    private DockerClient docker;

    @Test
    public void test1_expose_correct_port() throws Exception {
        assertThat(docker)
        .container("tomcat")
        .hasExposedPorts("8080/tcp");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2_be_able_to_connect_to_my_service() throws Exception {
        assertThat(docker)
        .container("tomcat")
        .isRunning();
    }

    @Test
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
    public void test3_findGoalTypes() throws Exception {
        RestAssured.given()
        .spec(requestSpecBuilder.build())
        .when()
        .get("/admin/goals/types")
        .then()
        .assertThat().body("status", equalTo("OK"));
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-universe</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.7</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.arquillian.cube</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-cube-docker</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.arquillian.cube</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-cube-docker-restassured</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.arquillian.cube</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-docker-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-remote-7</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I run this test with my embedded HyperSQL DB, I am getting the following error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not auto start container tomcat
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeSuiteLifecycleController.waitForCompletion(CubeSuiteLifecycleController.java:107)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeSuiteLifecycleController.startAllSteps(CubeSuiteLifecycleController.java:80)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeSuiteLifecycleController.startAutoContainers(CubeSuiteLifecycleController.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:75)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:116)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:436)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:479)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:171)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.ListContainersCmdExec.execute(ListContainersCmdExec.java:47)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.ListContainersCmdExec.execute(ListContainersCmdExec.java:19)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:23)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.docker.DockerClientExecutor.listRunningContainers(DockerClientExecutor.java:316)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeSuiteLifecycleController.isCubeRunning(CubeSuiteLifecycleController.java:115)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeSuiteLifecycleController.access$200(CubeSuiteLifecycleController.java:29)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeSuiteLifecycleController$StartCubes.call(CubeSuiteLifecycleController.java:142)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeSuiteLifecycleController$StartCubes.call(CubeSuiteLifecycleController.java:130)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.threading.ThreadedExecutorService$ContextualCallable.call(ThreadedExecutorService.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
    ... 17 more
```

Since I am new to docker and arquillian I don't have any clue at this moment.

I have installed docker toolbox in my windows 10 PC.

[image: Docker Details]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you start the container? What does `docker ps` show?

Comment: Just a small hint. Instead of `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` you can use `@InSequence` from Arquillian Core.

Comment: Try removing this strategy: polling from await section

Comment: @OleksandrShpota docker ps returns empty list.

Comment: @lordofthejars I have removed strategy: polling, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it possible you share the project on github so I can reproduce locally?